# Is Modis Daily LST Data the mean of all day's LST or it is on satellite path time?

Tags: remote-sensing, modis

I am looking for MODIS LST product which is exactly on the same time that satellite paths from a location, I have searched and found MOD11A1 but It seems that it is mean LST of Day.

Is there any product which is the same time of observing land with satellite?

To be more clear I know that there is a modis product `Mod11A1` this product is daily LST product but I don't know if it is LST of exact satellite path time (Lst on 10:30 local time) or it is a mean of all day time?

**update**

The answer is Yes, The Mod11A1 is exactly the LST data on time of flight and it is not all days mean value.

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking.  Could you please reword this question to clarify? Are you looking for similar MODIS scenes that are aligned temporally?  How would a split window help your analysis?

Comment: @Aaron I edited my question,Sorry for my bad English,In fact I want to have LST of the time which sattlite pathes my location,I want to know is MOD11A1 a daily mean of LST?

Comment: So that this is not too broad I think it needs to be split into two separate questions focused on finding the data product versus finding an algorithm.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes But In fact I have found the answer, I can not find any where to answer this question, Should I edit it and answer it in question itself?

Comment: Questions are for your question. Your answer should be written as an answer. But what single question are you asking and wanting to answer?  Once that is clear in your question it can be re-opened for you to answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo You know the I had asked to know if Mod11 is on-time of flight LST or not and it it is not How can I calculate LST for on-time of flight. However The answer is Yes, It is exaclty the LST on time of flight

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.